# init.el file loads, but not evaluating all of the expressions

Tags: init-file, parentheses

for example

```
(show-paren-mode t)
```

not getting evaluated, I have to run this function every time even though it is in my init.el file and other

Comment: How do you know it's not getting evaluated? How can we guess what else you might be doing in your init file that might be related? Try to provide a pared-down section of your init file that is sufficient to reproduce the problem, starting from `emacs -Q`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try invoking `emacs --debug-init` and see if you get a backtrace. The symptom you are describing is probably an error half way through the init file which is aborting the rest of the load.

EDIT in response to the comment: `emacs` looks first for `~/.emacs` (or `~/.emacs.el`) and if it does not find that it looks for `~/.emacs.d/init.el` (where `~` stands for your home directory). So just delete `~/.emacs` (and `~/.emacs.el` if it exists) and it will use `~/.emacs.d/init.el` instead.

Comment: I feel stupid, the .emacs file was the one got initialized not init.el, another question how can I set the init file path ?

Comment: In general, you should create a new question instead of asking a question in a comment.